# How can I extract a two digit from a sentence using regex expression?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to make a function that only extracts the two digit interger out of a specific regex expression.

```
def extract_number(message_text):
    regex_expression = 'What are the top ([0-9]{2}) trends on facebook'
    regex= re.compile(regex_expression)
    matches = regex.finditer(message_text)
    for match in matches:
        return match.group()

    # if there were no matches, return None
    return None
```

So that when I print

```
message_text= 'What are the top 54 trends on facebook today'
print(extract_number(message_text))
```

I will get the number 54.
If I write the following beneath, i get the whatever character that I put in (.+)...Why won't it work for numbers?

```
def extract_number(message_text):
    regex_expression = 'What are the top (.+) trends on facebook'
    regex= re.compile(regex_expression)
    matches = regex.finditer(message_text)
    for match in matches:
        return match.group()

message_text= 'What are the top fifty trends on facebook today'
print(extract_number(message_text))
```

Comment: As there is only one number in the string, use `(\d+)` to extract number from it and access it using first captured group. Here's [demo](https://regex101.com/r/NJew3u/1)

Comment: Use the first code, I got "What are the top 54 trends on facebook", not "54",

Answer (score 1):

The only problem with *both* your snippets is that you're not returning the capture-group result of interest, but the overall match:

```
return match.group()
```

is the same as `return match.group(0)`, i.e., it'll return the *overall match*, which in your case is the *entire input string*.

By contrast, you want index `1`, i.e., what the 1st *capture group* - the first subexpression enclosed in `(...)`, `([0-9]{2})` - matched:

```
return match.group(1)
```

To put it all together:

```
def extract_number(message_text):
    regex_expression = 'What are the top ([0-9]{2}) trends on facebook'
    regex= re.compile(regex_expression)
    matches = regex.finditer(message_text)
    # (See bottom of this answer for a loop-less alternative.)
    for match in matches:
        return match.group(1)  # index 1 returns what the 1st capture group matched

    # if there were no matches, return None
    return None

message_text= 'What are the top 54 trends on facebook today'
print(extract_number(message_text))
```

This yields the desired output:

```
54
```

---

Note: As @EvanL00 points out, given that only ever *1* match is needed, the use of `regex.finditer()` with a subsequent `for` loop that unconditionally returns in the first iteration is unnecessary and may obscure the intent of the code; the simpler and clearer approach is:

```
match = regex.search(message_text) # Get first match only.
if match:
    return match.group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for numeric/string:

```
def extract_number(message_text):
    regex_expression = 'What are the top ([a-zA-Z0-9]+) trends on facebook'
    regex= re.compile(regex_expression)
    matches = regex.findall(message_text)
    if matches:
        return matches[0]

message_text= 'What are the top fifty trends on facebook today'
print(extract_number(message_text))
message_text= 'What are the top 50 trends on facebook today'
print(extract_number(message_text))
message_text= 'What are the top -- trends on facebook today'
print(extract_number(message_text))
```

Output:

```
fifty
50
None
```